# What is the basis for saying that Adam was created without sin?

Tags: biblical-basis, sin, adam

I've googled multiple phrases and in different ways, but I haven't yet found any verse that says that Adam an Eve were created without sin. Or that simply says they were without sin before the fall, for that matter.

But I did find multiple scriptures saying Jesus was/is without sin...

It says Adam was made in the image of God...
But so is the rest of humanity.
And we are sinners.

Is it possible that Adam was sinful in nature, but just wasn't held accountable for his sins because he didn't know right from wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the fall, when Adam and Eve disobeyed God there was no sin in the world:

> Romans 5:12 through 14 NKJV  Therefore, just as through one man sin entered the world, and death through sin, and thus death spread to all men, because all sinned— 13  (For until the law sin was in the world, but sin is not imputed when there is no law. 14  Nevertheless death reigned from Adam to Moses, even over those who had not sinned according to the likeness of the transgression of Adam, who is a type of Him who was to come.

These Scriptures tell us that when Adam and Eve disobeyed God Death came into the world and so did sin, however; sin was not attributed to mankind until God gave Moses the law.

If this sounds confusing try to think of it this way God originally gave Adam instructions not to eat of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil lest they die. Adam by eating from the tree then brought death to mankind. Adam and Eve sinned when they disobeyed God and ate from the tree God told Adam not to eat thereof. However; from the time of their sin until God gave the ten Commandments to Moses no other humans ate from the tree, therefore no others were disobeying God's commandment. Sin is disobeying God. After God punished Adam and Eve, he sort of put man on a trial basis to see if they would use their free will for good or for evil, and that is why God regretted that he had made man and destroyed the World with a flood.

Then after the Flood even though he had chosen righteous Noah to repopulate the World man still gravitated toward evil.

So the answer to your question must be yes the original man, who we call Adam was created without sin, and did not disobey Cod until they ate from the tree which was the first sin.

Comment: Bye oohh ok.. I've always heard people say that Adam was created without sin. But then when started looking for scriptures that "Specifically" says Adam was created without out sin... I couldn't find one.. That's what threw my off.. So the second he disobeyed, was the second sin started living... I got it ..

Comment: It's Pauline theology.

Comment: @Bye. So, based on your answer, Eve changing the WORD OF GOD, was not a sin? (Genesis 3: 3)

Comment: @gideonmarx How do you know she changed the word of God?Perhaps she just stated it the way she thought she heard it. No two eye witnesses will give the same account of an incident. And when something is said to someone how often is it different when it returns to the one who said it first? That might be the reason Adam's punishment is constant, but Eve's is only occasional.

Comment: But there was sin in the world because the devil/serpent was there, already prepared to tempt Eve to eat of the forbidden fruit.

Comment: @jay_t55 Was sin or was evil present before the fall. Certainly Satan had already rebelled against God. Certainly that was sin against God. But sin (disobedience of God) began when Adam and Eve disobeyed God's command not to eat. that was when sin entered the world according to Romans 5:12 and according to verses 13 and 14 death was imputed to all mankind, but sin was not imputed to man until the Law was given to Moses. Adam and Eve sinned because God had given a command, but until God gave the law to man he was not disobeying God' command since the tree was inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

@ David Stratton, in reference to: "This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, **but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.** See How we are different than other sites? and What makes a good supported answer?

David, is not one a whole? Are not "groups" sets of one; like "one" group. Can a group be formed without the first "one?" Whether one idea, or anything else that goes on to form a group? Did not Jesus begin as just himself, just a "one?"

Also, the answer is definitely relative to sin. What is sin? The original question was; "What is the basis for saying that Adam was created without sin?" Therefore, the definition and true meaning of what constitutes "sin" must be established first, before asserting whether or not Adam was created without sin. Additionally, If I'm not mistaken, the true intent of this blog is not citing passages of the Bible, or to ascertain any information as to; authors, dates, originality, translations, or any anything relating to scriptures as to assess authenticity, or relation of current literature to original writings, so as to form a correct interpretation, since there are so many different interpretations. But God's words (instructions) to man have to be firm, unchanging, clear and to the point, no matter how many times rewritten, translated, and interpreted. It is ludicrous, and unholy to think that God's words and true intent could be "lost in translation." Is it not the intent of this site, and the blogging therein, for the purpose of getting at the truth? Therefore no "one" stone shall remain unturned, no matter how small, or unlikely it is retained to be hiding the truth.

Now to the original question. Is it not obvious that God wants mankind to learn about good and evil through experience and making mistakes along the way? Is not experience the best teacher? Well, God is the best at everything, including teaching. God could have made mankind fully wise to begin with, but in his superlative and infinite wisdom, or maybe just for his amusement, elected "other-wise", (no pun intended). But why cannot even the simplest minds understand what is "free will?" What is justice? God is Just, God is Good. Would God, in his Essence of perfect justice and goodness, allow free will to mankind when mankind had no knowledge of good and evil? How can a man exercise free will with this knowledge and not risk getting in trouble (sin)? How can man choose wisely and correctly? Would man just flip a coin; head is good, tail is bad?  We are all children of God, bar none. Ask Jesus. Did he not teach how to pray correctly? Did not Jesus, in leading others to pray, begin by saying; "Our Father" Note that it was not "My Father" nor ""God" who art in Heaven."" 
God is the Father of all and creator of everything.

God is the Greatest playwright, and He wrote this great drama of ours, and which is a comedy, a satyr play, and a tragedy, all in one. So just sit back, relax, and be entertained; the Author will come through the curtains, and make his stage appearance at the end. And along with accepting all the clamorous, long, and appreciative applauds, He will show His "humble" appreciation by bowing to the crowd.